# Could I memoize React Create Element Calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I were to write a component like this:

```
function thing() {
  return <p>asdf</p>;
}
```

could I possibly memoize it like this?

```
function thing() {
  const p = useMemo(() => <p>asdf</p>, []);

  return p;
}
```

Would this have any performance benefits or just more code?

Comment: You _could_, yes. In your example using the `React.memo` (making the component pure) is mostly going to accomplish the same thing. Does it make sense to do in your example? Probably not.